# Restrict su command

Tags: centos, root, su, restrictions

I have **user1** and **user2**. Normally, the user **root** can switch on all users with `su` command.

I want to restrict `su` command so that the user root can switch only to **user1**. It is possible??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  Root is root, and can do all and see all.

Comment: no way you can restrict access to root but you can restrict su to all users/groups

Answer (score 0):

As womble already said, you can't restrict access to `su` for `root`, since it could just change whatever you use to restrict `su` with, anyways.

If you want to restrict `su` in order to stop `root` from reading your personal files you could encrypt them (or your whole home directory).